# Sorting with low memory size

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, time, quicksort

What is the best way to sort a dictionary with 1Gbyte size(255 char for each word) with 2G of RAM?
I have already tried quicksort and didn't get the acceptable result.
This the quicksort code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXL 4000000
using namespace std;
void swap(char *&ch1,char *&ch2)
{
    char *temp = ch1;
    ch1 = ch2;
    ch2 = temp;
}

int partition (char **arr, int low, int high)
{
    string pivot = arr[high];    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(char **arr, int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Separately sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}


int main()
{
    fstream file("input.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
    fstream o("output.txt",ios::out);

    char **arr = new char*[MAXL];
    for(int i=0;i<MAXL;i++)
        arr[i] = new char[255];

    long long i=0;
    while(file)
    {
//words are sepearated by spcae
        file.getline(arr[i],256,' ');
        i++;
    }

    file.close();
    quickSort(arr, 0, i-2);

    for(long long j=0;j<i-1;j++)
    {
        o << arr[j] << "\n";
    }
}
```

It takes more than 10 minutes to sort the mentioned list but it shouldn't take more than 20 seconds.
(MAXL is the number of words in the 1G file and input words are stored in a text file)

Comment: What was wrong with quicksort ?

Comment: Any decent sorting algorithm is in-place, which means that 1GB is enough. Overhead will be insignificant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust **ANY** decent sorting algorithm?  The best ones for large datasets tend to be based on mergesort, which is not in-place.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The point that you're ignoring is that, while inappropriate for some purposes, it is a decent sorting algorithm that is not in place.  As another example look at Timsort, which is not only decent, but so good on real-world data that it has beaten everything else to become the default in Python, Java, and many other languages.  Again, not an in place algorithm.  (In part because it can resort to mergesort as a fallback.)

Comment: The point being that you can't just go to a standard library, take the recommended algorithm, and assume that it is in place.  Because there is a very good chance that it isn't.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you wish to use a private self-referential language, then sure.  Also see the No True Scotsman fallacy.  Back in the real world, standard libraries using recommended algorithms may or may not be in place.

Comment: @MBo It was fast enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Official definition of decent, https://www.dictionary.com/browse/decent.  Definition #2 is, *respectable, worthy*.  Any sorting algorithm that has become widely used and widely recommended based on real world use cases qualifies as respectable and worthy in my books.  A short list of the most widely used and recommended sorts are timsort, mergesort, and quicksort.  For more specialized uses you see heap sort, radix sort, bucket sort, insertion sort, and many more.  Plus there are online sorted data structures like red-black trees, btrees, skip lists and so on.

Comment: Note, most of these are not in place.  Because adding the constraint of being in place only makes sense if you're working within memory constraints that we usually aren't.

Comment: @btilly: you are quite right, go for Smoothsort.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That would be an excellent algorithm for this if you are constrained on memory and want the same general performance characteristics as timsort.  (`O(n log(n))` worst case, `O(n)` on nearly sorted data.)  If you are not constrained on memory, then timsort is strictly better.  Which is why we see timsort more often in the wild.

Comment: @btilly: did you read the question ?

Comment: @pedram OK, it was fast enough - but why unacceptable?

Comment: @MBoI meant it wasn't :)

Comment: @pedram If quicksort was not fast enough, then either you had a bad implementation, it wasn't actually an in place algorithm (many sort algorithms make a copy, then sort that), or your data came largely sorted.  If the problem is that your data came largely sorted then smoothsort is an excellent choice for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't fit it all in memory, a file-based merge sort will work well.

Comment: How can 1GB data fail to fit in 2GB memory ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because there is overhead in the in memory representation of raw data.  For example if you're using Python, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596342/calculating-the-real-size-of-a-python-string every string has 37 bytes of overhead.  So a 1 GB file of words will actually take several GB to load into memory.

Comment: @btilly: the question says 1 GB size. I take it literally.

Comment: it fits in the memory

Answer (score 0):

In-place algorithms are your solution. Find more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm):

> As another example, many sorting algorithms rearrange arrays into sorted order in-place, including bubble sort, comb sort, selection sort, insertion sort, heapsort, and Shell sort. These algorithms require only a few pointers, so their space complexity is O(log n).

Comment: QuickSort also requires `O(log n)` when it is properly implemented

Comment: @MBo Curious about where the `log n` here comes from. Is it the description of the size of the input?

Comment: @mrmcgreg Yes. `log(n)` is size of stack for quicksort. But `log(n)` space for mentioned algorithms is (too) formal definition based on bit size of variables needed for n range.

Comment: Several of the cited algorithms require O(1) space. I can't adhere to the last sentence.

Comment: time matters in this sort